# PS1 set to -bash-3.2$ after using chmod

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I was following instructions to install WSJT-X (a radio software) and it had me move a file named `sysctl.conf` to my desktop and run the following terminal commands:

```
  sudo cp $HOME/Desktop/sysctl.conf /etc/
  sudo chmod 664 /etc/sysctl.conf
  sudo chown  root:wheel  /etc/sysctl.conf
```

After running these commands, my terminal display changed to look like this:

[image: terminal pic]

Whereas previously my name was before the dollar sign. Also, my date and time are now displayed incorrectly (set 8 hours in the future). Can someone please help me find out what I did wrong and how I can fix it?

If it helps, I think I accidentally inserted a space in the second command so it became

```
sudo chmod 664 /etc/ sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Note: I'm a Linux guy and I have no experience with macOS. Take my answer with a grain of salt).</sub>

With `sudo chmod 664 /etc/` you removed execute bit from the directory and in effect you cannot access (read, write) items living within. This includes (among others):

- `/etc/profile`, where common `PS1` is defined,
- `/etc/localtime`, `/etc/timezone` or whatever macOS uses.

You need `sudo chmod 755 /etc` to revert this. Unfortunately no access to `/etc/sudoers` will probably prevent you from doing this directly. If you're extremely lucky, you still have a shell running as root (started for whatever reason before things went wrong) where you can invoke `chmod 755 /etc` without `sudo`. But probably you're not so lucky.

If the same problem occurred in my Kubuntu (no encryption or such), I would boot live USB Linux, mount the filesystem and fix the permissions. I don't know if you can easily fix macOS "from the outside" like this.

[This (oldish) question](https://superuser.com/q/313144/432690) deals with a similar problem where `sudo` doesn't work because of wrong permissions of `/etc/sudoers`. Possible solutions from answers:

> This may be one of the rare cases where running "Repair Disk Permissions" from Disk Utility might actually be warranted.
>
> If that doesn't work, follow […] suggestion of booting into single user mode to fix it

This one looks promising:

> Another approach is using `Automator.app`.
>
> Create a new workflow that contains something like the following:
>
> ```
> do shell script "chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers" with administrator privileges
> ```
>
> When you run it, it'll ask for your password and (presuming you're an administrator) it'll fix it.
>
> This also works if you've messed up the permissions on a parent directory (eg making `/` something other than 755).

Keep in mind you need to `chmod 755 /etc`, so don't blindly paste the above code. Your case falls under "messed up permissions on a parent directory".

Comment: Hey! Just wanted to say thanks so so much for your answer, I was able to fix the issue by entering single user mode and using 'chmod 755 /etc'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `+x` permission on a directory ("execute/traverse") in order to access any of the objects inside, regardless of having read permissions on those objects directly.

Your `chmod 664 /etc` command removed this by setting permissions to `u=rw,g=rw,o=r` (that's what the octal number decodes to), so now 1) the shell cannot access /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc, where the system-wide PS1 setting is kept; 2) the system cannot access /etc/localtime or its macOS equivalent, where the system-wide timezone parameters are kept.

Use `chmod 775` or `chmod a+x` on the directory to restore it. (7 and 5 decode to =rwx and =rx.)

(Actually I'm not sure if /etc is supposed to be group-writable, even on macOS, so you might also want `chmod 755` instead – or an additional `chmod g-w`.)